# Error: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I added a MVC 3 View Page of type Razor to the root of the existing ASP.NET MVC 3 project.
ViewName: TestView.cshtml
I opened the above file and tried to add the following line of code in the view:

```
<head>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Styles/Themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
```

For the line above I am getting an error: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context.
But when I am trying the same in a view within the Home or Account folder it is working fine for me.
Can any one help me to know what exactly I am missing?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is because you have created the view page in the **root** of the MVC project rather than in the **`Views`** folder.

In the Views folder there is a `web.config` file which has the following section:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            ...
```

The namespaces specified here are used to compile the views which is why you get the 'Url does not exist' error message.

You could try to copy the contents of the `web.config` to the 'web.config' root but I'm not sure this is a good idea.  And after doing so you may get a warning that there is no build provider registered but according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590052/actionmailer-net-stand-alone-there-is-no-build-provider-registered-for-the-exte) this will work perfectly fine.

I believe you may then have to register a new custom RazorViewEngine to specify the new paths to search for view`as the default view engine searches for views in the`Views` folder.

I'm not sure if you may need to make any other changes but unless you need to have Views in the root folder, I would recommend you move your view to the `Views` folder to hopefully allow you to get it working.

Comment: When I upgraded to next version I needed to manually edit & change to the **newer version**, `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0` and `System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0` in `\Views\Web.config`, so that the **IntelliSense** shouldn't show false errors in the razor `.cshtml` file.

Comment: @Dangerous If I could I would give you a huge smack on the face!!! kkkkk Thank you!!!

Comment: @Marco Alves - I don't know what to say! I'm flattered! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

try to check your packages.config
make sure it has same version with package version in webconfig.