# File cshtml in other location than the default 'Views' folder

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor, routes

In an ASP.MVC using angular, I have this structure

A folder 'App' (it's folder at root level) and some subfolders :

- Controllers (angular)
- Services (angular)
- Views (*.cshtml)

In a Index.cshtml file, placed in '/App/Views/SubFolder/, I'd like use the code below (or other razor) :

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/App/Controllers/mycontroller.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

I get this error: *CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context*

I tried this solution : [this solution](http://theshravan.net/blog/configure-the-views-search-locations-in-asp-net-mvc/) but not work, same error. How can I solve this ? I'd like have intelissense too in this page.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context in asp.net mvc3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229492/error-the-name-url-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-in-asp-net-mvc3)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the web.config may be missing from the views folder.