# Show all images from folder in Razor

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

Hello i'm trying to show all images from a directory, i dont know the name of the pictures and more will be added through time.
I have this but The "@url" gives me a does not exist, and if i take it off all images appear but just with the image loading error.
Root Folder Structure:
https://gyazo.com/e8db2f060b15335b9487b9ffce630a73

```
@foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), "*.png"))
{
    var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);
    <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Images/{0}", img.Name))" />
}
```

Comment: Where are your images? In an Images folder in the root folder of the application or content/images folder? Please edit the question and add the folder structure.

Comment: Maybe if you remove the line `<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images" + Model.ImageUrl)" />` it will work. Else, the image path ir wrong.

Comment: I tried but with the @Url i have an error that doesnt let me compile

Comment: what is the compilation error you get? I ran your code and it was ok

Comment: Does not exist on this context https://gyazo.com/daac655c66236eae858992c674f09bb8 @felix-cen

Comment: Then, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229492/error-the-name-url-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-in-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: I dont have a Views Folder and i didnt create a empty project @FelixCen

Comment: Put this at the top of your view, @using System.Web.Mvc

Comment: I tried putting on the Site Layout and on the top of the page and nothing