# set src path in img tag dynamically in asp.net web pages Razor

Tags: asp.net, image, razor, path, src

I am creating a web site with ASP.NET Web pages.
I need to set path for html img tag dynamically.
I searched everywhere they have given reasonable answeres but still they didnt work for me.

Image file path - `root/Images/11.jpg`

My code in `Upload.cshtml`

```
@{
    var fileName = "11.jpg";
    var path = "Images/" + fileName;

    <img src="@path" alt="image" />
}
```

I even tried

```
<img src=@path alt="image" />
```

Still it doesn't take the value from variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@{  
  string imagePath = Url.Content("~/Images/11.jpg");
}
```

Then your `img` tag can look like

```
<img src="@imagePath" alt="image" />
```

Comment: I get "Url doesnt exist in current context error" . I serche for that error too but didnt get satisfying answer .

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this:

```html
@{
  string iSrc = "~/imagePath/11.jpg"; //The src path.
}

<img src='@Url.Content(iSrc)' alt="img" />
```

The above answer from @izzy should work as well.

Comment: I get "Url doesnt exist in current context error" . I serche for that error too but didnt get satisfying answer .

Comment: hmm.. I might be wrong but I think you might have an issue with writing razor syntax in your views. Are you able to write in your view @Url. and get a pre-populated list of methods i.e. Action, Content, Encode, eqauls etc? if that is the case, check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229492/error-the-name-url-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-in-asp-net-mvc3

Answer (score 0):

correct code
var path = "/Images/" + fileName;